# How to copy text from one window and paste it into the code window? (VSIX C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, copy-paste, vsix

I want to programm a Plugin for Visual Studio (VSIX) with which I can copy / paste premade Text into my code. I intended to do it with ApplicationCommands.Paste, but I don't know how to bind my CommandTarget into the code-window to my caret. I thank very much to any ideas or tips in this matter in advance!

Selecting Text to Copy, then click Button to paste selected Text at the caret-cursor in the code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current IWpfTextView with IVsTextManager.GetActiveView() and then paste text with textView.TextBuffer.Insert for the current caret position. See the following complete code sample: [Insert text into the current active text view](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#TextBufferInsert).

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer and I am very sorry for my delayed reply. I have been trying to implement your solution and asked my professor as well as friends but... unfortunately I have failed to successfully add your provided code sample. 

I have added the Microsoft References and imports, yet when I add the codesample, my VisualStudio still says that it doesn't know VisualCommanderExt.ICommand, nor .text.UI, although the References are added.

Would you have any idea, what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @KonstantinHolm VisualCommanderExt.ICommand is needed only if you run the code in my Visual Commander extension.

Comment: Ah okay I see.

So it's about the IVsTextManager then. I have been working on that today, but I have trouble fulfilling the method-parameters of the GetActiveView (int fMustHaveFocus, IVsTextBuffer pBuffer, out IVsTextView ppView)

If I am to call that method over a button function from the XAML, I struggle finding the right parameters to call it with..